# The bridge index and crookedness of a knot

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

I am reading Dale Rolfsen's book *KNOTS AND LINKS*, at [page 115](https://books.google.com/books?id=naYJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA115), I can't figure out why the crookedness of a knot equals its bridge index. Please give me some hints or any references available, much thanks!

Comment: What's the definition of crookedness?

Comment: @RyanBudney In R^3, if you parameterize the knot, the crookedness of a knot K is the minimal number of relative maxima in the z-coordinate, the minima is taken over all knots of this type.
This definition is from Milnor's famous paper On the Total Curvature of Knots [link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969467?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: If you knew the knot in its "crookedness" position, you could assume the z-coordinate is a morse function on the knot, wouldn't that finish the job?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to state the definition of the bridge index in my question. It is defined to be the the minimal number of maximal overpasses in any regular projection of all knots in this type. It is said the two definition(bridge version and the overpass version) are equivalent, but I can't find out why.

Comment: I think this isn't meant to be a difficult problem -- you are likely "psyching yourself out".  Assuming the z-coordinate is morse and you're in the "crookedness" position, what you do is consider projections in directions "close to orthogonal to the z-axis".  Most such projections are regular knot diagrams, and they will be diagrams for the bridge index.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, I really need that encouragement (for this is only an exercise in the book and shouldn't be very hard), but I don't think this idea works. For example this three-twist-knot, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-twist_knot), the twist can be very complicated while it possesses only two relative maxima.

Comment: There are some exercises in that book that are quite hard -- if I recall I think I've heard Rolfsen say he hasn't solved all of them.  But this isn't one of them. The three twist knot case works fine with the idea I describe above.

Comment: I see, thank you for your patience!

Comment: Does it hold for the circle in the xy plane? It seems to have crookedness 1 and bridge number 0.